# UWP - function dynamic changing during runtime

Tags: c#, uwp

I have data that are flowing from web. I want to agregate this data with an simple function. I want to **send this function via internet** from other computer and change it during runtime of my programm.

For example pseudocode:

```
int incomingData = Web.GetData();
var agregatedData = Function(incomingData);
```

and I want to "somehow" change Function dynamicly. Input and output type will be the same.

```
public static int Funcion(int input) {
        return input * 2;
}
```

to

```
public static int Funcion(int input) {
        return input + 5;
    }
```

I tried DLLImport, but I could not create C# Exportable library. Right now, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Look into using delegates

Comment: If (a) apply x else if(b) apply y else apply z???

Comment: Or use interface and inject implementation based on some condition (i.e. strategy pattern).

Comment: Functions will be more complex and will be depended on network status. For now, I want to start somwhere. They will be programmed on other computer and sended through network. So, its impossible to use delegates.